# Kotlin - custom hashmap using generic types : cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter

Tags: arrays, kotlin, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to create a custom HashMap using Kotlin. Keep in mind, that I have only been using Kotlin for about a day, and have very limited experience with Java. I know the basics.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    // this field is not filled in yet.
}
fun HashMP<T>(){
    var map: ArrayList<Array<t>> = arrayListOf()
    fun put(key: T, value: T){
        map.add(*arrayOf*(key, value)) // problem: Cannot use T as reified type parameter. Use class instead.
    }
}
```

I was expecting it to add an array of the key and value to the arrayList. Please help me.

*Notice my username*

Comment: Apparently Stack Overflow didn't like me trying to italicize code. on line 7, 'arrayOf' doesn't use any asterisks.

Comment: You can [edit] our question to remove/fix mistakes. Note inside code blocks, "normal" Markdown formatting no longer applies (i.e., code blocks render the text as is, like `<pre><code>` in HTML).

Answer (score 4):

Unlike Lists, the type of an Array is **reified**, which means the type is known at compile time.

- Compile time: what's in your code before you run your app.
- Runtime: what is determined only while the compiled app is running.

In your function, the type `T` is only known at runtime. It's generic and could be set to anything. So inside the `put` function, `T` is unknown to the compiler--it could be anything, determined when the app is running, and it can be different each time it's called, depending on where it is called from.

Since an Array's type must be known at compile time, but `T` is not known at compile time, it is showing you an error.

This is one of the reasons you should prefer using Lists and MutableLists to using Arrays.

By the way, I think you meant to put `class HashMP<T>(){` instead of `fun HashMP<T>(){`.

It is possible to have a `reified` generic type in a function that is `inline`, but this won't work for generic types defined for a class. It only works for generic types declared in the function signature.

Comment: Side note, the reason we have this complicated situation is something called "type erasure" which is an unfortunate result of generic types not having been a part of Java from the beginning. They had to fit in the feature in such a way that old code would still work. Kotlin inherits this problem since it was designed to be interoperable with Java. In most languages newer than Java, this distinction between reified and non-reified types doesn't exist because types are always known.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're just starting out, the shortest path to success is to store the key and value in a [`Pair`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/) instead of a two-element array.

```kotlin
class MyCustomMap<K, V> {
    private val entries: MutableList<Pair<K, V>> = arrayListOf()

    fun put(key: K, value: V) {
        entries.add(key to value)
    }
}
```

It looked like you were trying to define a class, so that's what the code above does. It also adds a second type parameter, since a map's key and value often have different types.

Here's a discussion of how to solve the problem the compiler was complaining about. It's a relatively advanced topic, but you can come back to it later after learning about reified types.
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/reified-generics-on-class-level/16711